# How can I bind a double quote mark to a string in F #?

Tags: f#

In my imagination I would write code like this.
`let a = (""" )`
But this seems impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Espace the quote character with a backslash.

```
let a = "\""
```

or triple quote which is almost unreadable in this case.

```
let a = """""""
```